# Count how many files contain a string in the last line

Tags: bash, shell, tail

I want to count how many files in the current directory have the string `"A"` in the last line.

First solution: `tail -n 1 * | grep \"A\"| wc -l`

This works fine, but when there are more files it does `bash: /usr/bin/tail: Argument list too long`.
Is there a way to get around it?

Bonus points if I can also optionally get *which* files contains it.

EDIT: my folder contains 343729 files

EDIT2: @tso usefully pointed to the article [I'm getting "Argument list too long". How can I process a large list in chunks?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095) in his comment.

RESULTS:

@tso solution `for f in $(find . -type f); do tail -1 $f|grep \"A\"; done|wc -l` takes about 20 minutes

@lars solution `grep -P "\"A\"*\Z" -r . | wc -l` takes about 20 minutes

@mklement0 solution `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 sh -c 'tail -q -n 1 "$@" | grep \"A\"' - | wc -l` takes about 10 minutes

@james solution (in the comments) `for i in * ; do awk 'END{if(/a/)print FILENAME}' "$i" ; done` takes about 25 minutes

@codeforester `find . -type f -exec tail -n 1 -- {} + | grep -EB 1 '^[^=]+A' | grep -c '^==>'` takes >20 minutes.

*@mklement0 and @codeforester solutiona also has the advantage that if I want to change the grep pattern, the second time I run it it takes zero time, I guess it's due to some sort of caching.*

I've accepted @mklement0 answer at is seems to be the fastest, but I still like to mention @tso and @lars for their contributions and, based on my personal knowledge, an easier and adaptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `xargs` is able to overcome the max. command-line length limitation by efficiently *batching* the invocations into as few calls as possible.
- The shell's *builtins*, such as `printf`, are *not* subject to the max. command-line length.

Knowing this, you can use the following approach (which assumes that your `xargs` implementation supports the `-0` option for NUL-terminated input, and that your `tail` implementation supports multiple file operands and the `-q` option for suppressing filename headers.
Both assumptions hold for the GNU (Linux) and BSD/macOS implementations of these utilities):

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 sh -c 'tail -q -n 1 "$@" | grep \"A\"' - | wc -l
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `xargs -0 sh -c 'tail -q -n 1 "$@" | grep \"A\" - '`, with  `-` inside the single-quoted expression?

Comment: @codeforester: No: The unquoted `-` is needed _for `sh`_, because without this dummy argument the 1st `xargs`-supplied operand would bind to `$0` rather than `$1`, and then `"$@"` wouldn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `find`, `tail`, and `grep` this way?  This will be more efficient than having to loop through each file.  Also, `tail -1` will just read the last line of the files and hence very I/O efficient.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tail -n 1 -- {} + | grep -EB 1 '^[^=]+A' | grep -c '^==>'
```

- `find` will invoke `tail -1` in batches, passing [ARG_MAX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) file names at a time
- `tail` will print the last line of each of the file, prefixing it with the pattern "==> file_name <=="
- `grep -EB 1 '^[^=]+A'` will look for pattern `A` and fetch the previous line as well (it will exclude the file_name lines while looking for the match)
- `grep -c '^==>'` will count the number of files with matching pattern

If you don't need to know the name of the files having a match, but just get the count of files, you could do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tail -q -n 1 -- {} + | grep -c 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you! IT works, even if it output lot of `find: ‘tail’ terminated by signal 13`

Comment: Not sure if you knew, but if I change the grep pattern, it takes 0 time the second time. I guess it's due to some sort of caching. That's amazing!

Comment: Probably because of caching.  Would you be able to say which worked more efficiently?  My `find -exec` solution vs @mklement0's `xargs` solution?

Comment: @coderofester `xargs` solution is faster, takes roughly half of the time in my case, but I don't know if I can generalize this answer.

Answer (score 1):

try with find:

```
for f in $(find . -type f); do tail -1 $f|grep PATERN; done|wc -l
```

Comment: This approach works! Also, I might be wrong as this is not my field, but it looks like it search or pattern in the whole file, not in the last line only.

Comment: Looping over the results of `ls` (or output of `find` which is the same) is [dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: A more standard use of `find` in this way is to pipe through `xargs` or use the `-exec` option.

Comment: Alternative `find . -type f -exec sed '${/A/p};d' {} \; | wc -l`

Comment: Extremely inefficient for OP's case with more than 300k files.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ cat foo
b
a
$ cat bar
b
b
$ awk 'ENDFILE{if(/a/){c++; print FILENAME}}END{print c}' * 
foo
1
```

Comment: I like the approach, especially because it print filename, however having used `*` still gives `bash: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long`

Comment: Well, if the number of files is your problem: `for i in * ; do awk 'END{if(/a/)print FILENAME}' "$i" ; done` This won't give you the count, just the list of files so you can pipe it to `wc -l`. It just happens that I have a dir with a million files in it and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

If grep supports the `-P` option, this might work:

```
grep -P "A\Z" -r . | wc -l
```

See `man pcrepattern`. In short:

- `\Z` matches at the end of the subject also matches before a newline at the end of the subject
- `\z` matches only at the end of the subject

Try `\Z` and `\z`.

To see which files match, you would use only the `grep` part without the pipe to `wc`.

Comment: I changed `*` to `-r .` which means recursively look in current directory. That might work if current directory contains **only** the files you are interested in and **no other files** and **no other directories**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `grep -P "A" \z  -r .` instead ?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli No, the PCRE is `A\Z`: an "A" anchored to either `\Z` or `\z`, depending on your requirements. It might be possible that `"A" \z` in bash has a similar effect, but I am not sure about the space and the argument passing from bash to grep. I would put it in  quotes as one argument as written n the answer.

Comment: Does grep \Z just read the last line of a file or the entire thing?

Comment: @codeforester `\Z` is an anchor like `^` or `$`. Thus I believe it reads the whole file. But one has to check the source to be sure :).

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number of files:

```
grep -rlP "A\z" | wc -l
```

If you want to get the names then simply:

```
grep -rlP "A\Z"
```

Comment: Thanks @Samy . I am trying however to search in the last line of the files only, not in the full file.

Comment: No problem @LorenzoBelli. Sorry for not noticing, I have updated the answer with Lars' solution. Good luck.